# Regex with sscanf in c ignoring whitespace

Tags: c

I'm reading from an input file:

```
          # This is a comment

 Matrix A =
                    //NOTICE THIS LINE


# matrix A (2 diagonal line segments)

100 100

200 200
```

I can't figure how to extract the Matrix A from that line without the whitespace.
Right now I have

```
sscanf(buffer,"%s%*[^\n]", word);
```

I tried

```
sscanf(buffer,"%*[ ]%s%*[^\n]", word);
```

and

```
sscanf(buffer," %s%*[^\n]", word);
```

and so many others

It just doesn't ignore the whitespace, it copies it in the word variable as well as the matrix a.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you made a little bit clearer exactly what you want read in and what you want ignored. Since it's not clear, I'm going to take a guess:

```
sscanf(input_line, " %[^=]", matrix_name);
```

That *will* leave the trailing whitespace though, so you'll need to trim that separately:

```
rtrim(matrix_name);
```

Where rtrim is something like (ignoring sanity/error checking for clarity):

```
// warning: untested code.
void rtrim(char *string) { 
    int pos;

    for (pos=strlen(string); pos >= 0 && isspace(string[pos]); --pos)
        ;
    string[pos] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Just to prevent the above code from breaking:check  "pos>=0 && isspace(string[pos])" will be prevent your headache later on.

Answer (score 1):

sscanf does not handle regular expressions.

Comment: He's trying to use a scan set, not a regex -- and scanf (and friends) *do* handle scan sets.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `sscanf` doesn't have regular expressions. It takes a format specifier.

This is because C does not have regular expressions.

You either need to parse each line yourself, or use a regex library such as [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)

Comment: scanf *does* have scan sets though -- and that's what he's trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy:

```
char s1[100],s2[100],s3[100];
if( 3==sscanf(buffer,"%s%s%s",s1,s2,s3) && !strcmp(s2,"A") && !strcmp(s3,"=") )
  puts(s1);
```